# ggplot not ploting in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple graphs using ggplot. I have a .xls with 20 observations of 216 variables. The data is divided into 6, so there are 6 big blocks that I'm interested in. I've created this data using another loop, so that each block is divided by 3 (sets of 12 variables). I want to plot, for each one of the 6 blocks, the first variables of the smaller blocks. So in a plot I want to have: my_data[,i] , my_data[,i+12], my_data[,i+24], where i varies from 1:12 (so that i == 12 -> 12 + 24 = 36).

```
time= 1:20   # definir #periodos
title = c("pib", "c", "i", "l", "pi", "r", "w", "cl", "cc", "wrel","lrel", "yrel") # for titles
title = rep(title, 3)
plot_list = list()
    for (i in 1:12) {  
        df = data.frame(time,    
            as.numeric(my_data[,i],as.numeric(my_data[,i+12]), 
                as.numeric(my_data[,i+24])))
        p = ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y= as.numeric(my_data[,i])))
            + geom_line()
            + geom_line(aes(y=as.numeric(my_data[,i]), colour="nr = 0.32"))
            + geom_line(aes(y=as.numeric(my_data[,i+12]), colour="nr = 0.4"))
            + geom_line(aes(y=as.numeric(my_data[,i+24]), colour="nr = 10"))
            + scale_colour_manual("", breaks=c("nr = 0.32", "nr = 0.4", "nr = 10"), 
            values = c("green", "royalblue4", "orangered"))
            + labs(x = "periodos", y = "vg4")
            + ggtitle(paste0(title[i], "_vg4 for diff.nr - tax"))
        plot_list[[i]] = p
        print(p)
}
```

When I do this, only the third value (nr = 10) is being printed. Does anyone know what is happening? I've already tried to define my `data.frame` in different ways, but the output is always the same. 
Thank you!!

The data and .r file is in: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/efjtanbh5oznrg5/AADrhSUXOu3MYSCGLcFnNY_ea?dl=0

Comment: Help us help you by making your code reproducible (here that means providing data that works with your code). One issue is that you give ggplot the data frame `df`, but then you reference a separate data frame (`my_data`) within each call to `aes` (and inside aes you should only refer to column names; the data frame should be fed to `ggplot` or to the `data` argument of the `geom`). Have you checked whether the plotting code works outside of a loop?

Comment: Only the last `geom_line()` is read because it is last called and runs right above the other exact trends. I suspect the columns i, i + 12, i + 24 retain exact values. Check by rearranging geom lines and see if only the last will appear, here being `nr=10`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

First, the convention on SO is that answers are reserved for reproducible code that demonstrates a solution. Anything less, like speculation or opinion, belongs in a comment. Since your code does not run at all as is (there is no `my_data`), no one can answer you unless either you provide your data, or we create a sample for you. As you might expect, most people are justifiably unwilling to do the latter.

Second, this is not a good way to use `ggplot`. The idea is to use `aes(...)` to map the graph's aesthetics (e.g, x and y axis, colors, etc.) to *columns of your dataset*, using column names. So, something like this:

```
    df = data.frame(time,    
                    y1 = as.numeric(my_data[,i]),
                    y2 = as.numeric(my_data[,i+12]), 
                    y3 = as.numeric(my_data[,i+24]))
    p = ggplot(df, aes(x = time)) +
        geom_line(aes(y=y1, colour="nr = 0.32")) +
        geom_line(aes(y=y2, colour="nr = 0.4")) +
        geom_line(aes(y=y3, colour="nr = 10")) + 
        ...
```

would be better - although still not great.

Creating three lines using three calls to `geom_line(...)` is not a good idea either. Probably a better way would be something like this:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(data.frame(time,my_data[,i+c(0,12,24)]),
           id.vars="time", variable.name="nr", value.name="y")
p = ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y=y, color=nr)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_colour_manual("", labels=c("nr = 0.32", "nr = 0.4", "nr = 10"), 
                            values = c("green", "royalblue4", "orangered"))+
    ...
```

This uses `melt(...)` in the `reshape2` package to convert the data from "wide" format (data for different lines in different columns), into "long" format (all the y-data in a single column, with a second column (`nr` in the example) distinguishing the different lines. Now there's only one call to `geom_line(...)` .

Pulling this altogether:

```
## create artificial data set to demonstrate solution
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
my_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20*12*3), nrow=20))

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
for (i in 1:12) {  
  df <- melt(data.frame(time,my_data[,i+c(0,12,24)]),id.vars="time", variable.name="nr", value.name="y")
  p = ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y=y, color=nr)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_colour_manual("", labels=c("nr = 0.32", "nr = 0.4", "nr = 10"), 
                            values = c("green", "royalblue4", "orangered"))+
    labs(x = "periodos", y = "vg4")+
    ggtitle(paste0(title[i], "_vg4 for diff.nr - tax"))
  plot_list[[i]] = p
  print(p)
}
```

This produces 12 plots, the last of which is:

[image]

Finally, if you want to look at all the plots simultaneously, you can `melt(...)` the full data set (all 12*3 = 36 columns) and use ggplot facets:

```
df <- melt(data.frame(time,my_data), id.vars="time", variable.name="nr", value.name="y")
df <- cbind(df,plot=rep(title,each=length(time)))
df$nr <- rep(c("A","B","C"),each=12*length(time))
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=y, color=nr))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~plot, ncol=3)+
  scale_colour_manual("", labels=c("nr = 0.32", "nr = 0.4", "nr = 10"), 
                      values = c("green", "royalblue4", "orangered"))+
  labs(x = "periodos", y = "vg4", title="vg4 for diff.nr - tax")
```

[image]

The result is a bit cramped in this tiny format, but a larger plot would be OK I suspect.

Comment: Hello jlhoward. Thank you for your reply and advice. I keep having the same problem. When I plot all my graphs I get ony the red line. Is there a way that I could send you this? (My data seems to be exactly specified as the one you've created, i.e, with 20 obs of 36 variables).

Comment: what I'm doing is : data_TAX <- read.xlsx("D:/Users/E265297705/Documents/choques_antecipados_nr/Tax_nri.xls", sheetIndex = 1, header = F, endRow = 20) then data_TAX <- as.data.frame(dados_TAX) // and 
my_data <- data_TAX[,1:36]

Comment: Can you upload the `xls` file somewhere (Dropbox?) and post a link (in the question, not in a comment).

Comment: jlhoward I found it!!! The values are exaclty the same for the first, 12nd and 24th column!! it's probably a problem in the data! I'll try to fix it" thank you!!